# Photoshop closes files very slowly

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I try to close Photoshop files, each file takes about 5 seconds to close. I made a video to show you what I mean: https://streamable.com/5av58x

Notice that after I click 'close' on each file, the layer remains in the Layers panel for a few seconds and finally disappears allowing me to close the next file. I tried unchecking "use graphics processor" in preferences.

I'm using Windows 10 with a Nvidia Geforce RTX 2060 Super. What can I do to make the files close faster?

Comment: How big are the files? How much work have you done on them? All I can think is that it's clearing up the scratch disk.. is your scratch disk big enough & fast enough? Also, how much RAM do you have? Photoshop will use whatever is available. After a big session I've often seen it using 20GB or more.

Comment: The files can be any size; they all still take 5 seconds or so to close. They can be as small as a few kilobytes. My scratch disk is 370gb and I have 16gb of RAM. The length or size of the session doesn't seem to matter as all files take the same amount of time to close.

Comment: Then I'm not really sure - maybe try removing all plugins; re-add one at a time.  Check it's not trying to sync something to Bridge & that Adobe CC can correctly see your account is signed in, it may be hunting online & timeout. After that, I'd ask Adobe.